# AngularJS: Redirecting to a login page but remember the initial location?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have managed to get working security authentication so basically I do a redirect to the login route is the user isn't logged in.

This is working great, but i was wondering if anyone is doing something similar, once i have redirected to the login page i would like to come back to the original page once they have authenticated. Asp.net mvc does this using returnUrl on the querystring but this is really ugly i think.

So i have.

```
/items  // this show my items..
/login  // this is the login view.
```

so if a user goes to /items and isn't logged in I am currently redirecting to the login view but once a successful login has happened then i need to redirect the user to where he wanted to original go i.e. /items

I am doing this currently

```
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function ( next, current) {

        if (!authentication.getIsLoggedIn())
            $location.path('/login');

    });
```

If i am not able to pass the original url or store it some how then one the successful login has happened i wouldn't know where to send the user.

Love to hear any feedback.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're pretty close with watching `$routeChangeStart`, why not store the `next` value and then redirect to that after they have finished logging on?

Comment: You could use a parameter called redirect and set the url to which you need to redirect to.

Comment: Hi NuclearGhost, could you elaborate ? How would i redirect after I have done a login ?

Comment: See http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application, or Pawel and Peter's [book](http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book), chapter 6, "Security Interceptor Service", which uses the ideas from that blog post.

Comment: @MarcRajoc I think in the final book you find the idea outlined in 'Chapter 7: Securing Your Application' / Subchapter 'Creating a securityInterceptor service'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @NuclearGhost, you're super close. I handle this by having an AppLevel controller that just maintains the value of next, and does a redirectTo() to put them back to where they were going after authenticating.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. So if I understand this currently I need a property which I can set and get on a AppLevel controller, i think i will need to be able to get access to this property from different controllers... So how do you setup a applevel controller and call a property on it from the login controller? Can you elaborate further ?

Comment: At first when reading the various comments i thought i had to use the next variable that is injected onroutechangestart but ready a little further i see now that this has nothing to do with it and i would have to managed the property myself.

Comment: An "AppLevel service" is probably a better choice. Although application level controllers are possible, they seem to be discouraged. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17778495/1620112